# Not able to get the correct rows returned with datediff

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have 2 tables:

- pictures: picture_id, picture_date
- picture_user: pictured_id, user_id (user who posted the picture)

I want to get the users who have posted a picture in less than a year. I am getting the three columns (`pid`, `userid`, `p_date`) but some rows that have their `p_date` greater than 1 year are also returned.

```
SELECT p_picuser.pid,p_date,userid from p_pictures, p_picuser 
where p_pictures.pid=p_picuser.pid  
    AND (datediff(STR_TO_DATE(p_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),CURDATE())<365)
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data, and your expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL documentation states that datediff is date1 - date2.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

If you are comparing now to dates in the past (trying to find out how old something is), you need to subtract those dates from `curdate()` -- not the other way around.

See these examples from the documentation:

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-11-30 23:59:59','2010-12-31');
        -> -31
```

Comment: well I changed their order, and it is working thanx a ton but why it is working now , I am not able to understand can you throw some light

Comment: The datediff function always subtracts the second argument from the first, like in the examples that I have added. If you put them in the wrong order, it's not an error, but you will probably get a negative result. A negative result will always be less than your 365 comparison.